# How to delete row if only one returns?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database with the two columns
Chatroomid, userid

There are usually at least 2 people inside a chatroomid, but if a user leaves the chatroom, then there's only 1 row containing a specific chatroomid.

How can I delete a row if only 1 row returns from a query?

Comment: Use a CTE to gather those rows that are the only one for the given `chatroomid` and then delete them in  the outer query. See [DELETE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html) and [Data Modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Ah I see! Thank you! If you wanna post an answer I'll go ahead and mark it as solved.

Comment: Actually I may have been over thinking this. You could do this with a sub-query e.g. `delete from chat_table where chatroomid in (select  chatroomid  from chat_table group by chatroomid having count(chatroomid) = 1);`. Not tested, so proceed with caution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do so with the following query:

```sql
DELETE
FROM chat_rooms
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id
                 FROM chat_rooms
                 GROUP BY id
                 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```